# How to access a variable which is updated inside the function in outer scope in Cypress/Javascript?

Tags: javascript, cypress

Here is the problem statement. I am trying to find all items on a webpage and find the item with the minimum price using Cypress. The problem is, as long as I am inside the inner function, minPrice is correct. However when I try to print minPrice in the outer function, minPrice again gets assigned to it outer scope value. I am fairly new to JS, so looks like I am missing some basic JS concept here. I tried a lot of things like variable scoping, async/await (which cypress claims it doesnt need), but no success. Please help!

Below is the code.

```
getMinPrice(){
//Initialize to a very big number
  var minPrice = 10000;
 
  cy.get('.btn.btn-primary').each(function ($el, index,$list) {

    //For each element, do some parsing to get the price for the item
    var textToParse = $el.attr('onclick');
    var price = textToParse.slice(-4,-1);
    price = parseInt(price,10);
    
   //compare price with current MinPrice
   if (price < minPrice)
          minPrice = price; 
  });
 
  cy.log(minPrice); // Logs 10000 which is not what I am expecting
}
```

Comment: this will be helpful: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/introduction-to-cypress#Using-then-To-Act-On-A-Subject

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return the response from an asynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Thanks for your response. @alapan below solved it for me. Will go thru the docs in detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because JS works asynchronously your log statement is running before the value of `minPrice` is updated. To make sure that the log has the updated minprice, we can use `then` to make sure the log statement is run only after each has finished executing.

```js
cy.get('.btn.btn-primary')
  .each(function ($el, index, $list) {
    //For each element, do some parsing to get the price for the item
    var textToParse = $el.attr('onclick')
    var price = textToParse.slice(-4, -1)
    price = parseInt(price, 10)

    //compare price with current MinPrice
    if (price < minPrice) minPrice = price
  })
  .then(() => {
    cy.log(minPrice) //should have the updated value
  })
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That totally makes sense.

Comment: Follow up question here.  I am trying to return the minPrice to the calling function but Cypress throws a bunch of errors for mixing sync code with async code. How to tackle this? I tried chaining another "then" but didn't help.

Comment: I will suggest you to create a separate question for this as this goes beyond the scope of this question.